# How to use the original Guid in the SQL statement instead of the little endian one?

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, guid

I know we can

```
INSERT INTO "Table1" VALUES(X'57A00F3015310D4081AD4ADEF3EBDB5E');
```

But this little endian format is difficult to compare to the original Guid

```
300FA057-3115-400D-81AD-4ADEF3EBDB5E
```

How to use the original Guid in the SQL statement instead of the little endian one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to easily compare to the original without converting then store it as text.  It'll take more storage space and will be slower to read/write/compare, but it'll be more human readable.

Comment: I was looking for a SQLite script using `CONVERT`, `CAST` or `REPLACE` that could convert it for me.

Comment: @Jader Dias, SQLite doesn't natively support guids, so you won't find one.  You can write custom functions though easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [Table1] ([UID]) VALUES ('{57A00F30-1531-0D40-81AD-4ADEF3EBDB5E}');
```

I always do in this way, didn't find any problem.

Comment: forgot to tell, i write in this way with sqlite. hope mssql works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar frustrations and am experimenting with a querying tool to do conversion for me.

For now I get by with something like the below.

```
select quote(SomeGuid) from MyTable where name = 'Some Name'
```

Which returns

> X'12A0E85D8175514DA792EC3D9A8EFCF7'

Formatting the original guid and comparing to the above:

> 5DE8A01275814D51A792EC3D9A8EFCF7  -- original no dashes, uppercase
>   12A0E85D8175514DA792EC3D9A8EFCF7  -- quote(Guid)

I can get away with querying a partial Guid for filtering purposes.

Note % on the right side too - value is quoted

```
select * from MyTable where quote(SomeGuid) like '%A792EC3D9A8EFCF7%'
```