# Is there UID datatype in SQLITE if Yes then how to generate value for that

Tags: sqlite, uid

I am creating table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (id uniqueidentifier, foo text, bar text, PRIMARY  KEY (id))
```

How to insert  or generate value for id field in table foobar?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can argue that SQLite doesn't support data *types* at all. In SQLite3, you can do this, for example.

```
sqlite> create table test (id wibblewibble primary key);
```

SQLite will happily create a column with the "data type" wibblewibble.  SQLite will also happily create columns with the "data types" uuid, guid, and SuperChicken.

The crucial point for you is probably how to automatically generate a uid. SQLite can't help you much there.

You can leave it entirely up to the client program. If you're programming in python, use the [uuid module](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/uuid/).  In ruby, you have the [SecureRandom.uuid function](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom#uuid-class_method). Other languages have similar features or workarounds.

You can write your own uid-generating function in C. (See [Create or Redefine SQL Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html).) I'd call this a relatively extreme approach.

You can store it in either [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1039461/562459) or [text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5066392/562459) format.

---

Other conversations online suggest that there's a widespread misunderstanding about what a UUID *is*. A UUID is not simply a 128-bit random number. A UUID has structure and rules. See [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

Comment: thanks for your help .I generated UUID for android application like this                String sUUiDValue=UUID.randomUUID().toString();     and then inserted into table...

Answer (score 25):

Benjamin Berry's answer isn't right — it produces malformed UUIDs — but it shows an interesting technique using a subselect to generate randomness then selecting substrings from that. Here's something similar that I've confirmed does work:

```
select substr(u,1,8)||'-'||substr(u,9,4)||'-4'||substr(u,13,3)||
  '-'||v||substr(u,17,3)||'-'||substr(u,21,12) from (
    select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) as u, substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1) as v);
```

Some sample output:

```
c71122df-18e4-4a78-a446-fbf7b8f2969b
61e75f87-978b-4d9e-b587-bedcc2d23898
30eee0fa-2ff2-4ff5-b8ef-f99378272999
```

Comment: For me it created 20 exact same uuids for my migration copy from one table to another (where I changed _id from int to this uuid)

Comment: Same as @miroslavign, if used within one request to update all the table records for example, generates the exacts same uuid foreach record.

Comment: If you want to create random uuid for each line, I made a small mix.String u = "lower(hex(randomblob(16)))"; String v = "substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1)"; rawquery = "update table set guid = substr("+u+",1,8)||'-'||substr("+u+",9,4)||'-4'||substr("+u+",13,3)||'-'||"+v+"||substr("+u+",17,3)||'-'||substr("+u+",21,12)");

Comment: That's because random for computers are not really random, if the insert is happening too fast it's using the same random seed to get the "next" random number which means it will be the same number.  I suspect (but am not sure) that the random seed is milliseconds, if you can pause between inserts for a millisecond it will produce more "random" type results.

Comment: This has nothing to do with time, seeds, or milliseconds (pseudo-random generators are not seeded on every call), the expression is simply evaluated a single time by SQLite. Nowhere in the query do you request *multiple* values, you just say to use it multiple times, so SQLite uses one value that satisfies your request. Remember, SQL is not imperative, so an update/select is not necessarily a loop.

Comment: There is one serious flaw in the example. When included in a "set var=formula" in an update or multirow insert the optimization computes the formula once as an optimization. Therefore all the rows get the same value and that might not be the desired effect. I added a "random()*rowid" and now each row is computed separately. There is still a potential for failure of duplicate values even on a 16 digit random number.

Comment: @LordWabbit, true that "random is not really random", but anyone with the remotest bit of clue stirs the entropy pool a little between pulling hashes out; even if that stirring is completely mechanical (add one!), the hash algorithm makes the result _look_ completely different. You still don't have true randomness unless there's new entropy coming in, and it'll eventually loop back on itself, but even so the output looks good enough to fool humans -- what's shown here is _not_ just an example of PRNG behavior.

Answer (score 24):

Here is something similar which can be used directly as a expression:

```
lower(hex(randomblob(4))) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(2))) || '-4' || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1) || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(6)))
```

for example to be passed as default value for column:

```
sqlite> create table "table" (
  "id" char(36) default (lower(hex(randomblob(4))) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(2))) || '-4' || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1) || substr(lower(hex(randomblob(2))),2) || '-' || lower(hex(randomblob(6)))), 
  "data" varchar(255), primary key ("id")
);

sqlite> insert into "table" ("data") values ('foo');
sqlite> insert into "table" ("data") values ('bar');
sqlite> select * from "table";
947efcc9-4212-442a-b68c-eb6fbd8a7128|foo
a2c3857b-1eb4-40bd-aed2-6e8d68cc2ab8|bar
```

Comment: what's going on here: substr('89ab',abs(random()) % 4 + 1, 1)

Comment: It selects that next char to put is either '8', '9', 'a', or 'b'. It comes from UUID specs and tells that this is UUID variant 1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants

Answer (score 1):

needed this for a project

```
select SUBSTR(UUID, 0, 8)||'-'||SUBSTR(UUID,8,4)||'-'||SUBSTR(UUID,12,4)||'-'||SUBSTR(UUID,16)
from (
select lower(hex(randomblob(16))) AS UUID 
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces malformed UUIDs, for example: 284e630-2293-bea6-21b1095ac11fe4f04. It should have 8 chars in the first group, a third group of 4, and 12 chars in the last. Also, the UUID version bits should be 4, not random.

Answer (score 1):

I created a user-defined function (to generate the default value for a guid/uuid column in my c# application)

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
connection.CreateFunction("newid", Guid.NewGuid);
```