# SQLite UUID as column default

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to reproduce the SQL Server [`default NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) value for a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column in SQLite. It produces a UUID as a default for the column.

How can I do that in SQLite?

I found this page ([Is there UID datatype in SQLITE if Yes then how to generate value for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104662/is-there-uid-datatype-in-sqlite-if-yes-then-how-to-generate-value-for-that)) where they use a select statement but it is no good for DEFAULT.

**NOTE :** I am using the SQLite version implemented for browsers as I am using it through ionic and the cordova-sqlite plugin. So this does not contain all the features provided by SQLite and more importantly this does not contain the `RANDOM` function.

Comment: AUTO INCREMENT is not sufficient?

Comment: AUTOINCREMENT does nothing with UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`create function`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) to add a UUID function. By default you'd have to write it in C, but many SQLite drivers have a way to add functions in their native language. Here's an example in Perl using [DBD::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#dbh-sqlite_create_function-name-argc-code_ref-flags).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use DBI;
use Data::UUID;

# Connect to the database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db", "", "", { RaiseError => 1});

# Create uuid() which calls Perl to generate a uuid.
$dbh->sqlite_create_function("uuid", 0, sub { Data::UUID->new->create_str });

# Create a table using uuid() as the default.
$dbh->do(q[drop table if exists foo]);
$dbh->do(q[
    create table foo (
        id int primary key default (uuid()),
        name text
    )
]);

# Insert some rows using the default id.
$dbh->do(q[
    insert into foo (name) values ("you"), ("me")
]);

# Print out the rows.
my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(q[select * from foo]);
for my $row (@$rows) {
    say "$row->[0], $row->[1]";
}
```

And the result is.

```
E9768488-834F-11E6-AA60-F143DC5749B0, you
E976B69C-834F-11E6-AA60-F143DC5749B0, me
```